# How Can I use device camera as a Barcode reader/scanner in android independent of ZXing app?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I want to use device camera as a Barcode reader/scanner in android.
Although I saw ZXing's scanning app is available for using this functionality but I want to use this functionality independent of ZXing app.
Please Help

Comment: Have you tried Google? Or do people just punch their queries directly into SO questions these days?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use camera as barcode scanner

Use Zxing barcode scanner.
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/